# How not having the ACID properties of a Relational database helps Non-relational database perform better?

Tags: sql, database, nosql

I've read that some databases sacrifices ACID properties to have a better performance and scalibility.

Why not having the ACID properties helps a database having a better performance and scalibility across multiple servers?

Comment: If you reliquish data integrity and consistency, the engine needs to do less work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because doing anything requires time and resources so not having to enforce ACID compliance takes less time and fewer resources